# .NET SDK azure media service

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, azure-media-services

i've read a bunch of documentation on MSDN, however, is there also a SDK available for getting the azure media accounts? I want to iterate through each account => channel => program.

I can do it for each individual account with accountname and key, but I need to be one lever higher.

I know there is a REST-service, but I'm hoping that there is a .NET sdk for this (too).

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the ["official" Azure .Net SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/api/)? It has both a Media Services Management Library and a Media Services SDK documented

Answer (score 0):

Media related Azure management classes can be found under https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/AutoRest/src/ResourceManagement/Media

Official azure media .net sdk hosted at 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-media-services.

Comment: Perfect! Any change you know how I would get the region of  a specifiek AMS? Can't find any properties of the mediacontext...

Comment: it should be in location peoperty when you execute list command or get media account  -  

REST List all Media Services a subscription https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt750389.aspx

SDK - Task<AzureOperationResponse<MediaService>> GetWithHttpMessagesAsync  or ask<AzureOperationResponse<IEnumerable<MediaService>>> ListByResourceGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync